# In Android, is it possible to share login (session) information securely between two separate apps?

Tags: android, security

We have two apps, one is a VR app for Gear, which can only launch in VR mode. The other will be the normal app. What we want to do is have the authenticated user in the first app, be able to use the second app as if he was authenticated as well. A bit like how the Facebook and Messenger apps work where you can login to Messenger automatically if you're logged in with facebook.

Is it possible to be done without messing up the security/privacy of the user?

Comment: You can do it using [Content provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).

Comment: Thanks! If you want to write an answer about it I'll accept it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Content provider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html) can be used for data sharing between any applications.

Here are the links to get forward Ex:[1](http://codetheory.in/android-sharing-application-data-with-content-provider-and-content-resolver/) Ex:[2](http://mobikul.com/share-data-between-applications-using-content-providers/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the extra links! Very helpful.